# Semantic ui modal error

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I have already tried but could not find any answer to my question.

I want to use a semantic modal,the first,  [this](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/definition)!

my imports are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="moduli/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="moduli/semantic/dist/components/modal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="moduli/semantic/dist/components/modal.min.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js">         </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/semantic/dist/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/semantic/dist/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/function.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="moduli/semantic/dist/components/modal.min.js"></script>
```

Error on console :

```
modal.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: O.transition is not a function

modal.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: q.dimmer is not a function
```

when I click on a button, I call the follow js `function`:

```
$('.ui.modal')
   .modal({onShow: function(){}})
   .modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your error simply comes from the order of your `<script>` imports, since *semantic.min.js* depends on *jQuery* you must include *jQuery* before *semantic.min.js*

So use:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/semantic/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/semantic/dist/main.js"></script>
...
```

Instead of:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/semantic/dist/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moduli/semantic/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>  
...
```

You can see the working sample there:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="showModal" onClick="$('.ui.modal').modal('show');"></input>
  <div class="ui modal">
   <div class="header">Header</div>
   <div class="content">
  <p>some Content</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Hope it helps,